# Having placeholder columns when creating new database table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it good practice to add some placeholder columns when creating a database table with millions of rows, in case the schema gets changed later? More efficient to rename a column than to insert a new one?

Comment: No benefit to doing that whatsoever.

Comment: The overhead [appears to be minimal](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11664/do-empty-columns-take-up-space-in-a-table), but are you certain that you will ever use these columns in the future?

Comment: not sure, just planning ahead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many problems with adding "placeholder" columns to a table.

- These columns may take up useless space, and appear "sloppy".
- You may create too many columns now, and have columns that will never be used.
- You may not create enough columns now, and will have to end up creating more anyways.
- You don't know what the column data types will be at this time.

Always remember that if a column needs added at a later date and will not be used for any of the current rows in the table, you can still keep the table normalized by creating a smaller table that holds this information, then link them by using the primary key.

Let me know if you have any questions about this. I hope this helps!

Comment: so even empty columns take up space? not just in the schema

Comment: As far as memory goes, empty columns usually take up negligible amounts. I say usually because the datatype of the column may affect the amount of space it takes up.